Preview does not appear in Sublime Text 4
I use Sublime Text 4 (4180) and LaTeX Tools on my Mac(M1, Sonoma 14.6.1) to write LaTeX documents. LaTeX Tools offers instant preview of math texts. It used to work without problem until the phantoms for the preview suddenly disappeared a few days ago, and I need help.
Here are some symptoms and things I tried:

I don't see a phantom on even the simplest code such as  $x$. (In particular, it is not because preview document does not load the same packages, as suggested by cabohah.)
I ran  the built-in system check, but the status sections all say "available."
I have also tried reinstalling Sublime, but to no avail.

I honestly have no idea what is causing the trouble. Does anyone have a clue why this is happening?

Welcome to TeX.SX! I'm not a sublime text user. But without any information about the code you've tried to preview, what happens from the working state to the not working state (updates, changes in the document etc.) etc. it is really hard to help you. Without such information I would guess the preview fails because the preview document does not load the same packages. See, e.g., https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools/issues/1572 and similar issues.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

OK, I found a solution. I went to Settings > Package Settings > LaTeX Tools > Settings - User and set the preview math scope to
"preview_math_scope": "text.tex.latex meta.environment.math"

Previously, the scope was "text.tex.latex meta.environment.math.block", and it seems that the last block was causing the trouble. (I do not know what triggered the change in the scope, though.)
That said, I just found out that LaTeX Tools does not officially support Sublime 4. While I am happy with my experience with the combination of Sublime 4 and LaTeX Tools, maybe I should switch to a different editor...
